# Unable to consume kafka messages using apache storm

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have developed an application to consume the kafka message using apache storm,  when i run topology using in LocalCluster in eclipse it works fine and messages consumes properly, but when i run this using storm command **(bin\storm jar ..\kafka-storm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.kafka_storm.util.Topology storm-kafka-topology)**, the topology started but unable to consume any message, it there something wrong i am doing, or guide me what things i can do to find the problem

**Topology Code**

```
public class Topology {

public Properties configs;
public BoltBuilder boltBuilder;
public SpoutBuilder spoutBuilder;   

public Topology(String configFile) throws Exception {
    configs = new Properties();

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
        configs.load(is);
        //configs.load(Topology.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));
        boltBuilder = new BoltBuilder(configs);
        spoutBuilder = new SpoutBuilder(configs);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private void submitTopology() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Entered in submitTopology");
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();    
    KafkaSpout<?, ?> kafkaSpout = spoutBuilder.buildKafkaSpout();
    SinkTypeBolt sinkTypeBolt = boltBuilder.buildSinkTypeBolt();
    MongoDBBolt mongoBolt = boltBuilder.buildMongoDBBolt();


    //set the kafkaSpout to topology
    //parallelism-hint for kafkaSpout - defines number of executors/threads to be spawn per container
    int kafkaSpoutCount = Integer.parseInt(configs.getProperty(Keys.KAFKA_SPOUT_COUNT));
    builder.setSpout(configs.getProperty(Keys.KAFKA_SPOUT_ID), kafkaSpout, kafkaSpoutCount);


    //set the sinktype bolt
    int sinkBoltCount = Integer.parseInt(configs.getProperty(Keys.SINK_BOLT_COUNT));
    builder.setBolt(configs.getProperty(Keys.SINK_TYPE_BOLT_ID),sinkTypeBolt,sinkBoltCount).shuffleGrouping(configs.getProperty(Keys.KAFKA_SPOUT_ID));

    //set the mongodb bolt
    int mongoBoltCount = Integer.parseInt(configs.getProperty(Keys.MONGO_BOLT_COUNT));
    builder.setBolt(configs.getProperty(Keys.MONGO_BOLT_ID),mongoBolt,mongoBoltCount).shuffleGrouping(configs.getProperty(Keys.SINK_TYPE_BOLT_ID),Keys.MONGODB_STREAM);


    String topologyName = configs.getProperty(Keys.TOPOLOGY_NAME);

    Config conf = new Config();
    //Defines how many worker processes have to be created for the topology in the cluster.
    conf.setNumWorkers(1);

    System.out.println("Submitting Topology");
    //StormSubmitter.submitTopology(topologyName, conf, builder.createTopology());
    System.out.println("Topology submitted");

    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology(topologyName, conf, builder.createTopology());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String configFile;
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Missing input : config file location, using default");
        configFile = "application.properties";
    } else{
        configFile = args[0];
    }

    Topology ingestionTopology = new Topology(configFile);
    ingestionTopology.submitTopology();
}
```

}

**Spout Code**

```
public class SpoutBuilder {

public Properties configs = null;

public SpoutBuilder(Properties configs) {
    this.configs = configs;
}
public KafkaSpout<?, ?> buildKafkaSpout() {
    String servers = configs.getProperty(Keys.KAFKA_BROKER);
    String topic = configs.getProperty(Keys.KAFKA_TOPIC);
    String group = configs.getProperty(Keys.KAFKA_CONSUMERGROUP);

    return new KafkaSpout<>(getKafkaSpoutConfig(servers,topic,group));
}

protected KafkaSpoutConfig<String, String> getKafkaSpoutConfig(String bootstrapServers, String topic, String group) {
    return KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, new String[]{topic})
        .setProp(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, group)
        .setRetry(getRetryService())
        .setOffsetCommitPeriodMs(10_000)
        .setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(FirstPollOffsetStrategy.UNCOMMITTED_LATEST)
        .setMaxUncommittedOffsets(250)
        .setProcessingGuarantee(ProcessingGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        .setTupleTrackingEnforced(true)
        .setEmitNullTuples(false)
        .setRecordTranslator(new DefaultRecordTranslator<String, String>())
        .build();
}

protected KafkaSpoutRetryService getRetryService() {
    return new KafkaSpoutRetryExponentialBackoff(TimeInterval.microSeconds(500),
        TimeInterval.milliSeconds(2), Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeInterval.seconds(10));
}
```

}

**Bolt Builder**

```
public class BoltBuilder {

public Properties configs = null;

public BoltBuilder(Properties configs) {
    this.configs = configs;
}

public SinkTypeBolt buildSinkTypeBolt() {
    return new SinkTypeBolt();
}

public MongoDBBolt buildMongoDBBolt() {
    String host = configs.getProperty(Keys.MONGO_HOST);
    int port = Integer.parseInt(configs.getProperty(Keys.MONGO_PORT));
    String db = configs.getProperty(Keys.MONGO_DATABASE);
    String collection = configs.getProperty(Keys.MONGO_COLLECTION);
    return new MongoDBBolt(host, port, db, collection);
}
```

}

**SinkTypeBolt Code**

```
public class SinkTypeBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private OutputCollector collector;

public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    String value = tuple.getString(4);
    System.out.println("Received in SinkType bolt : "+value);
    if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()){
        collector.emit(Keys.MONGODB_STREAM,new Values(value));
        System.out.println("Emitted : "+value);
    }
    collector.ack(tuple);   
}

public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    this.collector = collector;
}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declareStream(Keys.MONGODB_STREAM, new Fields("content"));
}
```

}

**MongoDB Bolt**

```
public class MongoDBBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private OutputCollector collector;
private MongoDatabase mongoDB;
private MongoClient mongoClient;
private String collection;

public String host;
public int port ;
public String db;

protected MongoDBBolt(String host, int port, String db,String collection) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.db = db;
    this.collection = collection;
}

public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    this.collector = collector;
    this.mongoClient = new MongoClient(host,port);
    this.mongoDB = mongoClient.getDatabase(db);
}

public void execute(Tuple input) {
    Document mongoDoc = getMongoDocForInput(input);
    try{
        mongoDB.getCollection(collection).insertOne(mongoDoc);
        collector.ack(input);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        collector.fail(input);
    }
}

@Override
public void cleanup() {
    this.mongoClient.close();
}

public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public Document  getMongoDocForInput(Tuple input) {
    Document doc = new Document();
    String content = (String) input.getValueByField("content");
    String[] parts = content.trim().split(" ");
    System.out.println("Received in MongoDB bolt "+content);
    try {
        for(String part : parts) {
            String[] subParts = part.split(":");
            String fieldName = subParts[0];
            String value = subParts[1];
            doc.append(fieldName, value);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
    return doc;
}
```

}

**pom.xml code**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.kafka_storm.util.Topology</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include> **/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

[Storm UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36S23.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, you are remembering to use the StormSubmitter line in Topology, rather than the LocalCluster when you submit the topology with `storm jar`, right?

Also please check that you've started all the right daemons, i.e. `storm nimbus`, `storm supervisor` should be running as a minimum (plus your Zookeeper install)

The next places to look would be in your log files. In the Storm directory, you'll have a `logs` directory. Look in the `logs/worker-artifacts/<your-topology-id>/<your-worker-port>/worker.log` files. Those will hopefully get you on the right track to figuring out what's going on. I'd open Storm UI, find your spout and look up which worker ports it's running on, so you can look in the right log files.

Comment: Thanks Stig,
I checked the logs you mentioned, there was a issue of Java versions as I am using java 8 for devopment but using java 10 for Strom deployment.

It works fine now.